# Retain dynamic drop down value from php array after submit

Tags: php

I have a dropdown list being dynamically populated from an array but I can't seem to get the syntax correct so that it displays the selected value after the form is submitted.

This is what I have so far..

```
<select id="country" name="country">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
<?php
foreach ($countrylist as $value => $country) {
    echo '<option value="' . $value . '" ' . ($selected == $value ? ' selected' : '') . '>' . $country . '</option>';
} ?>

</select>
```

It seems that somewhere along the line I have made a mistake but I can't seem to work out where.

Comment: That all looks good to me. Chances are that `$selected` is not being set to the proper value. Maybe you can post some code as to what is happening with that?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response.  I'm not sure which code it is that you would like to see?  The list populates ok but when the form is submitted it defaults back to the first option.  the array name is $countrylist if that halps?

Comment: @tatty27: You're comparing each value against `$selected`. The code you have shown looks fine, so the best guess is that `$selected` doesn't contain the selected option in the dropdown.

Comment: Where and when do you set $selected ?

Comment: to be honest I didn't set the value $selected, I have been searching forums on how to do this and this looked like the best solution so I tried it with my array name etc but I can't get it working (probably because $selected doesn't have a value.  Given that the name of the array is called $countrylist and the select id is country what would be the best way to do this?

Comment: If you submit the page, and then return to the page (eg having the form visible, clicking save, and then reloading the page) then the selected value should be in either `$_GET['country']` or `$_POST['country']`, depending on the submit-type.

Comment: Thank you, that was what I was missing, I substituted $select with $_POST['country'] and it worked.  If you want to officially answer the question I will accept it.  Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are comparing each `$value` with `$selected`, `$selected` needs to hold the value of the selected option. In this case it is hold in `$_POST['country']`.